# Microsoft Graph : $filter/ $search query parameter, cannot find any documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft, graph

My document library hierarchy is like this:

[image]

I try to use the Graph API to extract some information or documentations from my Document Library in SharePoint Online, for instance:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root/children?$filter=name eq 'AS-BUILT'` > Works well - no problem

My question is when I use the:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root?$filter=name eq 'AS-BUILT' AND document_x2000_type eq 'For information'`

I cannot find anything. As a matter of fact, there will be a document align with the conditions.

Another question is I have 800,000 documents inside, which one is better for my status to use `$filter`, `$select`, or `$search`

Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

$filter is not supported

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-query-parameter?tabs=http

- `$filter`: Helps you find documents that meet certain conditions.
- `$select`: Lets you choose what information you want about each document.
- `$search`: Helps you find documents based on a search word or phrase.

If you have many documents (like 800,000), `$search` might be easier to use for your needs.